# How could I stream the video with python in one script, and then load it and analyse with OpenCV in another?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using this code from https://github.com/log0/video_streaming_with_flask_example to stream video from camera and make it public. I am able to do it with this code, but I need to analyse the video with OpenCV in external application, so I need to load it in that python script.

I use this code

camera.py

```
import cv2

class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Using OpenCV to capture from device 0. If you have trouble capturing
        # from a webcam, comment the line below out and use a video file
        # instead.
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        # If you decide to use video.mp4, you must have this file in the folder
        # as the main.py.
        # self.video = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):
        success, image = self.video.read()
        # We are using Motion JPEG, but OpenCV defaults to capture raw images,
        # so we must encode it into JPEG in order to correctly display the
        # video stream.
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
        return jpeg.tobytes()
```

and for main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from camera import VideoCamera

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', debug=True)
```

When I run the both scripts I get the page 127.0.0.1:5000 and I can see the video. What I need to do, is to stream the video like this, but to import it in some external python script that uses OpenCV to do some analysis like this

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('127.0.0.1:5000')
```

but it is not working, I am getting error

```
warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:808)
warning: 127.0.0.1:5000 (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:809)
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow, file C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 331
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I am aware that localhost is not visible from outside, but I will put it later on the public ip as soon as I solve this to make it work without importing VideoCamera class. It is enough if it works on my computer now.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46636126/2286337).

Comment: This article is not helpful