# Open a video file using OpenCV and GStreamer

Tags: windows, python-2.7, opencv, gstreamer

I began to study opencv. Open with opencv a videofile so easy. But I do not understand how you can open the file using the gsteamer. I read the documentation.
As written in the documentation,must do so:

> filesrc location=videofile ! decodebin name=decoder decoder. ! queue
>   ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! osssink decoder. ! videoconvert !
>   xvimagesink

or

> filesrc location=something.mp4 ! matroskademux ! decodebin !
>   videoconvert ! appsink

But I don’t quite understand how to correctly set the path to any file and still use gstreamer. How can I open any video file using opencv and gstreamer?

```
import cv2

#filepath = input("enter the path to the video")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("filepath", cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) # OpenCV2 version 2 used "CV_CAP_PROP_FPS"
duration = frame_count/fps
print('fps = ' + str(fps))
print('duration (S) = ' + str(duration))
minutes = int(duration/60)
seconds = duration%60
print('duration (M:S) = ' + str(minutes) + ':' + str(seconds))
cap.release()
```

P.S: Gstreamer is working. I checked the command `print(cv2.getBuildInformation())`.

My OS windows 8.1.

Comment: Does your opencv installation have gstreamer? Make sure you install one that is built with gstreamer. or build it from source like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51213730/how-to-get-gstreamer-live-stream-using-opencv-and-python

Comment: Shawn, yes, i have installation with gstreamer. I has 2 problems: 1) I can’t figure out how to use the Gstreamer in my code correctly. 2) I would like to transmit the video path from the command line in VideoCapture. But when I  write cv2.VideoCapture('C:/Python27/aaaa.mp4'), i has some errors.

Comment: using `r` before the path will fix that. `cv2.VideoCapture(r'C:/Python27/aaaa.mp4')`

Comment: Thanks. One problem remains. How can I use gstreamer in my code?

Answer (score 0):

For MP4 files:

```
import cv2

WINDOW_NAME = 'Video'

filepath = "./my_video_file.mp4"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(
    'filesrc location={} ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink'.format(filepath),
    cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER
)

cv2.namedWindow(
    WINDOW_NAME,
    cv2.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL | cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL | cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO
)

cv2.resizeWindow(
    WINDOW_NAME,
    int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),
    int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        return
    cv2.imshow(WINDOW_NAME, frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

To change the video size/quality such pipeline could be used:

`filesrc location={} ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=640,pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1 ! appsink`
with `cv2.resizeWindow(WINDOW_NAME, 640, 640)`.

See [Bug 725418 "videoscale ignores add-borders property - Always maintains aspect ratio"](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/gstreamer-bugs/2014-March/120902.html)