# Segmentation Fault when trying to initialize cv2.VideoWriter with gstreamer arguments in OpenCV-Python

Tags: python, opencv, video, segmentation-fault, gstreamer

I am attempting to use gstreamer in order to convert my OpenCV frames into a rtp stream, but I have trouble even opening up the webcam and other files.

I was having trouble with getting my script to work well, so I ran this:

```
export OPENCV_VIDEOIO_DEBUG=TRUE
```

This is the code that I used:

```
# Cam properties
fps = 30.
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Set camera properties
frame_width = cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH
frame_height = cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, fps)

# Define the gstreamer sink
gst_str_rtp = "appsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc noise-reduction=10000 tune=zerolatency byte-stream=true threads=4 ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000"

# Check if cap is open
if cap.isOpened() is not True:
    print "Cannot open camera. Exiting."
    quit()

# Create videowriter as a SHM sink
out = cv2.VideoWriter(gst_str_rtp, 0, fps, (frame_width, frame_height), True)
```

I get this error every time I try to run it:

```
[ WARN:0] VIDEOIO(cvCreateCameraCapture_V4L(index)): trying ...

[ WARN:0] VIDEOIO(cvCreateCameraCapture_V4L(index)): result=0x1f5a7a0 ...

[ WARN:0] VIDEOIO(cvCreateVideoWriter_FFMPEG_proxy(filename, fourcc, fps, frameSize, isColor)): trying ...

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What should I do?

Comment: You've to add gstreamer flag when initializing video writer. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46636126/2286337) for a proper use of gstreamer.

Comment: So you're suggesting to just add a "-v" for "-v appsrc ! videoconvert ! . . ." for the code? I am still getting a segmentation fault.

Comment: Did you read the link?

Comment: Are you referring to the "CAP_GSTREAMER"? What would be the correct way to initialize it in Python?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to initialize the VideoWriter with the GSTREAMER parameters as such.

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter(gst_str_rtp, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, 0, fps, (frame_width, frame_height), True)
```